# What is the phase of a vibrating beam?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, resonance

In my lecture notes, when talking about AFM Cantilever, there is graph shown below with following caption:

> Resonance of a vibrating beam.
> Amplitude (a) and phase (b) of a beam driven at a frequency $ω$.
> (c,d) show amplitude and phase at  $ω=ω_0$ as a function of the distance between probe (tip) and surface.

> [image: Blockquote]

Can anyone explain what the phase is in the contex of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This refers to the relative phase between the response of the system relative and the driving force on the system.  Typically a phase difference of 0 would mean that the oscillations are exactly in phase with the driving force, while a phase difference of π would mean that they are exactly out of phase.

Different conventions exist concerning whether a positive phase difference corresponds to the system leading or lagging the driving force, and I'm not sure what's common in this case;  you will need to consult your sources carefully to ascertain the conventions they're using.